# Jquery working on console but not on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to hide a div after certain time once its loaded and its working when I do this in the console but it doesnt work when I put this code in the actual webpage.

```
 (function ($) {
  if ($('#insightera_widget_content').length) {
  $('#insightera_widget_content').delay(10000).fadeOut('slow');
  }
}(jQuery));
```

The div **insightera_widget_content** cannot be seen when I view the source code as well, but I can see it on the Inspector. It loads from some external widget.

[image] 
I have tried using the below to the page too and it doesn't work at all.

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() { 
    if ($('#insightera_widget_content').length) { 
    $('#insightera_widget_content').delay(10000).fadeOut('slow');}
    }); 
    </script>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I've checked it out and it works. Did you attach jquery into your script?

Comment: Script is fine, but you run it while `#insightera_widget_content` is not on page. It should be in callback function after you load its content, ok?

Comment: @skobaljic but its loading from some third party js file. I cannot change anything there.

Comment: What error message are you getting whenit's not working?

Comment: Than you have to set `setTimeout` or `setInterval` and check for its existance. Maybe that third party script also triggers some window/element event, check it.

Comment: @skobaljic that's the answer I provided, but it was downvoted. Do you see anything wrong with that approach? Seems straight forward to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setup a `setInterval()` to check for the existence of the element, and once it finds it, run your jquery and clear the interval.

```js
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  if ($('#insightera_widget_content').length) {
    $('#insightera_widget_content').delay(10000).fadeOut('slow');
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 1000)

/* you don't need this part - just simulating the widget adding the code to the page */
setTimeout(function() {
  $('body').append('<div id="insightera_widget_content">insightera_widget_content</div>');
}, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you've downvoted me, please tell me what's wrong with this answer so that I can improve and learn from my mistakes.

Comment: @MichaelCoker : I don't know it is the proper way to solve to my issue but it works like a charm. Thank you.